# Java main function has to throw exception but who will handle it?

Tags: java

I write a simple program that output "123" into "output.txt". I noticed that if I do not add "throws FileNotFoundException", java could not even compile.
If I do not have throw clause console says Unresolved compilation problem. Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException on main.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWrite("output.txt");
    out.println("123");
    out.close();
}
```

1. Why do I have to add throw clause, I tried creating a "output.txt" before building it but problem exists.
2. Does it mean that main method will throw FileNotFoundException but what is function that will handle it?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler telling you that you need to add a `throws` declaration just means that you have called a method that (can) throw a checked exception. You could, instead, just `catch` the exception yourself, so that your method *can't* throw the exception by leaving it unhandled.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWrite("output.txt");
    out.println("123");
    out.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // do whatever else
  }
}
```

To address your specific questions:

1. You have to add a throw clause because if you call a method that throws an exception, and you don't catch it, then your method will throw that exception. Creating the "output.txt" file will not help, because that method still might throw (how do you know that it will exist at runtime just because it's there when you compile?).
2. If the `main` method throws an exception, the program will crash.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I learned C and Python, but they do not force me to do exception handle before file is not even compiled. So in this case, PrintWriter was detected that in runtime it may(or can???) produce exception, but my code does not seem have proper handling??

Comment: @Akrios https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/checked-vs-unchecked-exceptions-in-java/ Java has the concept of a "checked" exception which is one that must be explicitly handled (or thrown) for compilation to succeed.

Answer (score 1):

The `FileNotFoundException` is a checked exception, meaning that you should define how to handle this exception.

There are 2 ways :

- Handle the line with a `try-catch` block
- Declare the method using `throws`, this means that the caller will
  have to handle the exception.

In your example, you've decided to declare the `main` with `throws`. It means that on exception your program will terminate.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I learned C and Python, but they do not force me to do exception handle before file is not even compiled. So in this case, PrintWriter was detected that in runtime it may(or can???) produce exception, but my code does not seem have proper handling??

Comment: Not sure about C or Python, but Java expects you to handle an uncheced exception manually. To answer your question yes. If you check the constructor of `PrintWriter` you can see that it throws `FileNotFoundException`. So it's expecting your code to handle that. How to handle that has been provided in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. There are 2 kind of exceptions in Java checked and runtime exceptions. Java language requires developer to handle checked exceptions. If a method can throw checked exception that exception has to be declared with throws keyword in method definition.
2. Yes, main method will throw this exception. Java language specification [11.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.3) says that if exception is not handled then thread is terminated. And [12.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.8) says that program terminates when all non daemon thread terminate. So in this case program will simply exit.

[Javadoc for PrintWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter-java.lang.String-) reveals to us that PrintWriter tries to create the file but will fail with FileNotFoundException if file with that name cannot be created. Maybe folder is missing write permission or existing file is locked by some other process, like text editor?

Answer (score 0):

Answering your first question.

In Java, there are two types of exceptions:

1) **Checked**: are the exceptions that are checked at compile time. If some code within a method throws a checked exception, then the method must either handle the exception or it must specify the exception using throws keyword.

Since FileNotFoundException is a subclass of IOException, we can just specify IOException in the throws list and make the above program compiler-error-free.

2) **Unchecked**: are the exceptions that are not checked at the compiled time. Error and RuntimeException classes are unchecked exceptions

Coming to your second question:

You might think that the public static void main method in Java or the main function in C is the real entry point of your program – but it isn't. All high-level languages (including C) have a language runtime that initializes the program and then transfers control flow to the entry point. In the case of Java, initialization will include:

- setting up the JVM
- loading required classes
- running static initializer blocks.This can execute user-defined code before main is invoked. These blocks aren't supposed to throw exceptions.

There are a variety of ways to implement exception handling, but for the purpose of this question, they all can be viewed as a black box. The important thing however is that the language runtime must always provide an outermost exception handler that catches all exceptions that aren't caught by user code. This exception handler will usually print out a stack trace, shut down the program in an orderly fashion, and exit with an error code. Properly shutting down the program includes destroying the object graph, invoking finalizers, and freeing resources such as memory, file handles, or network connections.